# Why is my Extbase Object only validated on create but not on update

Tags: validation, typo3, extbase

I have a problem with TYPO3 object validation which I haven't been able to solve. For sake of simplicity let's say I have objects A and B, with a relation A <- 1:n -> B.

Object A has some properties that are marked @validate NotEmpty in the A model and this works fine if I create a new instance of A using a form (a validation error is generated and the field gets a css error class added).

If the object already exists and I change it (using a standard edit/update construct) validation seems to be complete ignored and I can persist the object with an empty value for the property that is marked @validate NotEmpty.

I have the suspicion that the behaviour could be connected to other relations in Objects A and B (B has a link to it's A parent e.g.), because it seems that during validation all child objects get validated as well, even though I annotated all of the relation properties with @ignorevalidation.

Is there anything I can do to debug this behaviour? Is there any way to prevent Extbase from validating child objects or any objects connected via relation properties?

Answer (score 2):

I know this problem from TYPO3 6.2 and I think it's still present in 7.6+. I've wrote a german article about this behavior which might can help you. http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2016/02/typo3-extbase-validierung-von-unterobjekten-deaktivieren.html

Summary: In the initialize-Actions you can change the validators and remove them from specific attributes.

```
public function initializeCreateAction() {
    if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('newPosten')) {
        /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\ConjunctionValidator */
        $conjunctionValidator = $this->arguments->getArgument('newPosten')->getValidator();
        // REMOVES ALL VALIDATORS! MODIFY TO MAKE IT MORE SPECIFIC!
        foreach ($conjunctionValidator->getValidators() as $validator) {
            $conjunctionValidator->removeValidator($validator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paul. I had actually found your article before posting here and it definitely seems to be close to what I am experiencing. I have checked what validators are generated using your code snippet and in fact, additionally to the validators I explicitely annotated every relational property is either checked with a CollectionValidator or ConjunctionValidator. The problem with this is, that I can remove all property validators or none...since there doesn't seem to be a method to remove property validators. I could only remove my objects' ConjunctionValidator completely.

Comment: I also described this in an article for usage of dynamic validation depending on form selections. I know it seems to be ugly, but you can create a new model with relations to subobjects without validators and get the ConjunctionValidator of this "proxy"-Model and bind it to your request in the initialize-Acitons. See: http://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2015/05/typo3-extbase-dynamische-validierung-von-models-je-nach-formularauswahl.html